# Prototype Cells - First one with no content view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

This is strange... I added a table view to a view controller, set number of prototype cells to 3, but after they got added automatically, the first prototype cell doesn't have a content view, nor can I add one as subview.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: hm..try to delete this cell and add again..

Comment: Weird, works like that :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possibly some kind of bug. Delete this cell and add again.

Comment: Having the same problem - got around it by setting the number of protype cells to one more than i wanted and then deleting the first one

Comment: are there any alternatives to this? I tried to delete the tableview,tableviewcell, recreate the process, clean, resart xcode. But still no contentview on first cell.

Comment: unfortunately no. I've run into this bug only once and fixed it like this. You are welcome to add another way of fixing this)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is when you create a dynamic prototype for cell it's content view doesn't have an id.

In my case I just opened storyboard file in text editor and noticed that my cell actually have a content view:

```
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="zco-1o-WJ4">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
</tableViewCellContentView>
```

But if you see, there is no id for that.

So I found another cell with correct content view and saw that difference was only in id for content view. Correct content view was looking like this:

```
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="VQc-uV-1iJ" id="UR5-S8-XX9">
```

So I just added id for content view and it became visible in storyboard file. You can put any unique id and this could be work.

Above solution works fine. But now you know the cause.